# Force operating system to run a program with no other programs in the background

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, real-time

I wrote a program to find speed of read and write to a flash drive in c. I have a big text file that gets written to a flash drive. It outputs the time it took to write the file, and then reads the newly written file, and outputs the time it took to read it.

I know that a computer I run the program on will be running other things in the background while I run the c program, which will make the times inaccurate.

In order to make times more accurate, I want to make it so the computer will devote all resources to my c program while it runs. Is there such a way to make a c program run in real time this way?

I will test this program on linux, mac, and windows.

Comment: No strictly possible in general. With Linux, google for real-time process scheduling.

Comment: Not possible. One viable alternative is to run the program many, many times and perform statistical analysis on the results.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is impossible. Think about it for a while: If the computer were to do nothing else than execute your program: who would do the memory management while your program is running? **You would have to be your own operating system!**

There is another flaw in your test: The file is most-likely not read from the flash drive anyway. It would come from the disk cache i.e. RAM on any modern operating system. To forego this, you would have to clear that cache, for example by ejecting and re-inserting the drive.

Comment: You can manually disable disk caching, though again, not in a cross-platform way. Of course, then you're not measuring practical performance.

Comment: @Sneftel of course. My point is more that what he is asking is likely not what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

No. Neither (normal, consumer-used) Linux, nor MacOS, nor Windows supports real-time processing. (Note that existing benchmarking suites ask you nicely not to run other programs while they're doing their thing.)

With that said, all of these OSes prioritize running foreground processes, so the results you get aren't likely to be too far off unless you've got a lot of other stuff running at the same time. You should use multiple trials to get the most precise results.

The absolute best you can do in one of those OSes is to run your benchmark as a kernel process. That's a very difficult thing to do, however, and makes it absolutely impossible to get any sort of cross-platform compatibility.

Alternatively, you can run your benchmark on an actual real-time OS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was as I suspected. My backup plan was to do as you said, and run the program many times and average the results, and also close other programs while I run mine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish your goal, you will most likely have to interface with the hardware directly, without the assistance of the operating system.  It can be done if you are willing to write a kernel module that also acts as a driver for the flash drive.  As a kernel module, there are ways to force your code to run to completion before yielding the processor.

Comment: this does not solve the real time processing problem.